# Sum a list of indirect ranges from a dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of ranges in a column. The ranges are part of a dynamic named range and are in text format.

```
$A$1:$A$5
$A$6:$A$10
$A$11:$A$15
...
```

The aim is to `SUM` the values between each range in the dynamic range as calling the dynamic range should iterate through all the ranges. However, does not with `=SUM(INDIRECT(<dynamic_range>)`. This formula only returns one value which does not correspond with the first range in the dynamic range.

For example, return the sum of the first range, then in the next row, return the sum of the second range, so on and so forth until the end of the dynamic range.

I am trying to keep this preferably as a formula and not in VBA.

Comment: `SUM()` will always return one value. Can you explain little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also if the ranges are in the same sheet as the result there's no need for INDIRECT (volatile), but you can use INDEX instead.

Comment: @Harun24HR The aim is to sum the values in column A depending on the range in the dynamic range. Basically, return the sum of the first range, the sum of the second range, so on and so forth through the dynamic range.

Comment: @P.b How would I go about using INDEX for this matter?

Comment: @Henry are your Named Ranges static? i.e is it always $A$1:$A$5 for the first range?  Also what are the 3 Range Names?

Comment: Something like `=INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(5,,ROW()*5)-4)` (in row one it will spill A1:A5, on row 2 it'll spill A6:A10, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIF not SUM with the dynamic array formula in Office 365 it will spill the sums:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(rng),"<>")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding volatile INDIRECT you can use:
`=SUM(INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(5,,ROW()*5)-4))` when you have office365 or `=SUM(INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:1)*5-4):INDEX(A:A,ROWS($1:1)*5))` for older versions.

[image: Capture]

PS this is provided that the change of range is in same steps of 5 cells each time.